# C#/.NET user32.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Как получить **X** и **Y** мышки из *user32.dll* ?
Вроде бы есть функция *GetCursorPos*, но я не понял как её использовать.

Результат должен выглядеть, как 2 переменные (напр. mouseX, mouseY).

---

Спасибо!

Comment: Собственно, а зачем? Можно использовать [MousePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx) или [Cursor.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Бывший дельфист, что ли? Со своим WinAPI.

Comment: У вас WinForms или WPF? И да, пользоваться WinAPI без надобности не нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение координат экрана:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

private void WritePoint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(out p))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p.X) + ";" + Convert.ToString(p.Y));
    }
}
```

Конвертирование пикселей в WPF единицы:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

private Point ConvertPixelsToUnits(int x, int y)
{
    // get the system DPI
    IntPtr dDC = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); // Get desktop DC
    int dpi = GetDeviceCaps(dDC, 88);
    bool rv = ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, dDC);

    // WPF's physical unit size is calculated by taking the 
    // "Device-Independant Unit Size" (always 1/96)
    // and scaling it by the system DPI
    double physicalUnitSize = (1d / 96d) * (double)dpi;
    Point wpfUnits = new Point(physicalUnitSize * (double)x,
        physicalUnitSize * (double)y);

    return wpfUnits;          
}
```

Собираем всё вместе:

```
private void WriteMouseCoordinatesInWPFUnits()
{
    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(out p))
    {
        Point wpfPoint = ConvertPixelsToUnits(p.X, p.Y);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(wpfPoint.X) + ";" + Convert.ToString(wpfPoint.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: using System.Runtime.InteropServices; и писать функцию (WritePoint) только для получения координат и записи на консоль, которая даже не возвращает ничего, это излишне, и да, если WPF, то консоль как-то странно :), лучше бы MessageBox.

Comment: Указывайте источник http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981853/5472058